# Define an ActionMethod has [HttpPost] in mvc4 HandleErrorAttribute extension class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to know whether an actionmethod has [HttpPost] or not. My code is given below. But it is returning null always.

```
string actionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
Type controller = filterContext.Controller.GetType();
MethodInfo method = controller.GetMethod(actionName); //OK Code
var attribute = method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(HttpPostAttribute), true); //returns null
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure that `controller.GetMethod(actionName)` returned non-null? Also this is very fragile. Casing matters. Also what if you have 2 controller actions with the same name: one for Get and one for Post which is quite a common pattern. This `controller.GetMethod(actionName)` will crash.

Comment: For the same reason i want to filter it with [httppost].